# Phoca Gallery: Error with Intergration of Facebook Albums in Gallery

Tags: facebook, gallery, integration

So, same Problem like the Guy before and alot more people on the web, but this time i try to make a good discription. My english is not perfect, but please realise that i really try to tell you the details here.

1. There is a Function in the Famous Phoca Gallery Plugin for Joomla to integrate whole Facebook-Albums into the Gallery-System and show them next to the local ablums and pictures of the website in the same style and css.

here the detailed description by the deveopener of phoca gallery, how this integration normaly works, please look here:
http://www.phoca.cz/documents/2-phoca-gallery-component/443-displaying-facebook-albums

1. So, easy to tell: U have to create an facebook-application, give phoca galery the usernamem & pw, App-ID and secret-nr and it gets the rest of the needed data automatically via facebook.
2. Then, you have to create an new category inside of the phoca galerysystem and define the Facebook-Album you want as source. this is finally the step, that doesnt work with my page. U have to select the choosen facebook user, this is working, but if I try to select an fb-album of this user, i just get following error:

Facebook API Failure: Unknown method (3)

Normaly, on most Systems its working, but there are a few systems, where its just not working. Have a look on this forum, a lot of people have the same error like me. 
http://www.phoca.cz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23126

Developeners of Phoca tried to fix, but finally they started to tell the people, they should ask the developeners of facebook, because since now nobody was sucessfull to fix or just find the error.

So, this is now the try to tell u about this problem, maybe there is a way

Hopefully u are not just closing this, if anybody knows the problem and and have a fix, PLEASE tell

Comment: Hi, when you updated your Phoca Gallery to latest version, do you still get the same problem?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about phoca gallery, but I've developed a plugin for showing your Facebook albums (fanpage only) into your Joomla site. Thousands of people are using it successfully on their sites. It also has a WordPress version.

BTW, It's not free.

[JFBAlbum](http://www.srizon.com/jfbalbum)

[JFBAlbum Demo](http://www.srizon.com/jfbalbum-demo)